# How to debug if it exits immediately without error message?

Tags: c++, opencv

A problem occurred while linking the external library "OpenCV".

There are no error messages either during the build process or at runtime.

When executed, it exits without any response.

If you delete line that uses OpenCV's "Mat" object, it works normally.

If "Mat" object is used, cout of the previous line is not executed.

If use Sleep for a long time before that and use the "Mat" object in the next line

When executed, it exits immediately without Sleep.

If try-catch is used for Mat object, it does not branch to catch.

Is there any other way for me to check the error message?

For example, pdb file, Windows System Event Viewer, etc.

winapi.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>

int main() {
  std::cout << "start" << std::endl;
  cv::Mat mat;
  while(_getch() != 'q');
  return 0;
}
```

build command

```
cl.exe ^
  -DUNICODE ^
  -D_UNICODE ^
  /utf-8 ^
  /EHsc ^
  /W4 ^
  /ZI ^
  /Fe: C:\work\winapi\winapi.exe ^
  C:\work\winapi\winapi.cpp ^
  /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um" ^
  /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" ^
  /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" ^
  /I "C:\work\opencv\build" ^
  /I "C:\work\opencv\modules\core\include" ^
  /link ^
    opencv_core453d.lib ^
    "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64" ^
    "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x64" ^
    "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\lib\onecore\x64" ^
    "/LIBPATH:C:\work\opencv\build\lib\Debug"
```

I am using Visual Studio Code, but when I use notepad and cmd.exe the result is the same.

VSCode's "cppvsdbg" debugger doesn't help either. Because it ends immediately.

Or could it be possible to get additional information from "cppvsdbg" after it has already been shut down?

Comment: *I am using Visual Studio Code* -- `cl.exe` -- That doesn't look like "Visual Studio Code" to me.  That looks like the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler command.  Visual Studio Code is an IDE, not a compiler.  Having said that, have you considered just getting the Visual Studio Community IDE, and not have to fight with Visual Studio Code to run the Microsoft compiler tools?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you are right. The reason is that I've had this problem for a very long time, so I tested it by removing all suspect elements as much as possible. So I left out even the IDE. The reason VSCode is mentioned is simply because I was hoping that "cppvsdbg" would help with troubleshooting. As mentioned, the problem is the same even without VSCode.

Comment: Did you use the Visual Studio debugger?   The `try/catch` will not work unless the `Mat` constructor is documented to throw an exception.  Second, you are not using `mat` at all in your program -- are you sure that the compiler didn't simply optimize away that line of code?  Maybe if you actually were using `mat`, you would get different results?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The result is the same both with and without the Visual Studio debugger. And rather, I expected it to be optimized. If it was optimized and that part was completely deleted, the code before and after it had to work. But the whole program doesn't run at all. Additionally, even if we explicitly run Mat's constructor, the result is the same. For example, "cv::Mat mat(100, 100, CV_8UC4);"

Comment: `cv::Mat mat;` is already running the default constructor. I'm not familiar with `cppvsdbg`. Does it tell you at all how the program exited (e.g. with a non-zero exit code)? That might indicate if the program was killed by a signal.

Comment: @enoeht *The result is the same both with and without the Visual Studio debugger.*  -- When using the Visual Studio debugger, did you hit the "F5" key to just run the program?  If you did, don't do that.  Use `F10` to single step through the code.  The debugger would have stopped at the very first executable line of code in `main`.

Comment: @Kevin I'm not familiar with "cppvsdbg" either. I just see that the running item in VSCode's debug window came and went for a very short time. I don't know how to check the exit code for the result that has already disappeared. Do you know of any other tool that can execute any exe file and check the exit code in Windows environment?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Even if I press F10 key, it does not execute step by step and exits immediately. Also, if I create a breakpoint before Mat and press F5, it does not reach the breakpoint and exits immediately. Of course, if I delete Mat, all functions of the debugger work normally. (If I delete the Mat, it runs well one step at a time using F10. Also, if there is no Mat, it will break normally at the breakpoint.)

Comment: @Kevin Thank you very much! I tried "echo %errorlevel%" , and as a result of -1073741515, I got information about a file system error and a problem with the dll reference. It was of great help.

Comment: `-1073741515` is `0xc0000135` and that means `STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND`. debug the issue using "Dependency Walker". run your program under DW's control so it can see all the LoadLibrary calls